# Calculating Double FLOPS for GPU

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I am using OpenCL to do some GPU computations and I am having a hard time computing the FLOPS of my card. The formula for FLOPS in float I am using is pretty straight forward:

```
frequency * cores * (instructions/cycle)
where: instructions/cycle is 4 for CPU and 2 for GPU
```

The problem is, how can I compute the theoretical peak performance for a particular card in Double precision. My card is the GeForce GTX 580.

--Daniel.

Comment: So you have the formula, and you have the hardware from which you can easily google the specs to get things like frequency and number of cores, what are you missing? Edit: besides, you can get the theoretical GFLOPS value immediately by googling, too...

Comment: Yes, you can get it for Float, but not for Double. As far as I know, the Double FLOPS are computed a bit differently than the Float FLOPS. I have found this link, but I don't know if the formula for Double also applies to the GTX 580 https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/412132/gpu-single-and-double-precision-flops/

Comment: Have you read https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/495177/cuda-programming-and-performance/what-is-the-double-precision-flops-rating-of-the-gtx580-/ ?

Comment: No, but I think this is what I was searching for. Turn it into an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/495177/cuda-programming-and-performance/what-is-the-double-precision-flops-rating-of-the-gtx580-/
:

```
[1.544 GHz] * [512 CUDA Cores] * [2 double precision floating point operations/8 clock cycles] = 198 GFLOPS.
```

Especially [this seibert's comment](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/495177/cuda-programming-and-performance/what-is-the-double-precision-flops-rating-of-the-gtx580-/post/3543931/#3543931) in the above thread goes in depth to the details of where the 2/8 comes to the equation.